# Como desenvolver manuais de usuários?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, documentação

Me apareceu uma situação aqui que me instigou a procurar algum software que me permitisse criar um manual de usuário bem feito.

O que acontece é que fui encarregado de desenvolver o manual de usuário do sistema que temos aqui por uma solicitação de um cliente. O sistema é gigante e se eu fosse fazer na mão um manual de usuário iria durar meses.

Então resolvi procurar alguns softwares que automatizassem alguma parte desse trabalho para me ajudar.

Pois bem, achei alguns softwares que ajudam, quase todos são pagos, há alguns gratuitos.

São eles: [HelpNDoc](http://www.helpndoc.com/), [Dr.Explain](http://www.drexplain.com/pt/), [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html), [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) e [Help&Manual](http://www.helpandmanual.com/index.html). Alguns disponibilizam APIs para integração com algumas linguagens.

Minhas dúvidas são:

- Como posso desenvolver um bom manual de usuário?
- Existe alguma norma ou padrão que deva ser seguido na hora de confeccionar um manual?

Comment: Todos são bons, teste todos e veja qual melhor te atende, desenvolver um manual, depende muito da complexibilidade e o publico do manual, e o padrão seria com um bom português e seguir normas da ABNT :D kkkk

Comment: @Rod, você já usou algum deles? KKKKKK, esse é um detalhe bem importante!

Comment: Eu usei só o CKEditor para edição de textos, rs

Comment: @ÉrikThiago A tag de documentação tem dois links em inglês que podem ser um ponto de partida. Vou atualizar esse Wiki de acordo com as respostas que forem aparecendo aqui.

Comment: @Rod eu achei o CKEditor muito básico... To testando o HelpNDoc, e aparentemente ele é bem completo.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, poxa cara, valeu mesmo, vou dar uma lida!

Comment: Se for um software de uso via WEB seria interessante partir para documentação em videos primeiro, em vez de textos. Uma forma mais rápida de fazer um manual é usar o esquema de FAQ antes de ir documentando passos. Muitas vezes os passos dependem de entender legislação ou processos internos da empresa o que precisará de aprofundamentos que nada têm a ver com o proprio software.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Para você não se preocupar tanto com a formatação, e conseguir focar na escrita do conteúdo da documentação, sugiro essas ferramentas:

- usando o LaTex você aproveita um template de formatação já existente e gera um PDF de alta qualidade. Um exemplo de uma excelente documentação feita em LaTex: [manual](https://github.com/eclab/mason/blob/master/mason/docs/manual/manual.pdf) / [código-fonte do manual](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclab/mason/master/mason/docs/manual/manual.tex)
- usando a sintaxe MarkDown você pode criar uma documentação em HTML.
- o Git vai te ajudar a manter o controle de versões da sua documentação.
- Um bom editor de texto, como por exemplo o Sublime Text, que tem plugins pra te ajudar a usar as ferramentas acima.

Answer (score 7):

Os softwares que ajudam fazer manuais de usuário são os comuns para ajudar produzir qualquer conteúdo escrito. Será principalmente um processador de texto e eventualmente outros que possam ajudar ilustrar o texto. Não tem nada que ajude escrever o manual do usuário. Eventualmente pode-se usar algum software para colocar em um formato específico que possa ser lido por algum software padrão, mas eles não farão o trabalho de meses virar dias, ele apenas fará um acabamento depois que o manual estiver pronto.

Os outros softwares descritos na pergunta ajudam documentar API, aí não estamos falando de manual de usuário. Eles ajudam um pouco, mas é basicamente formatação, a documentação da API deve ser feita com cuidado e isto será responsável por quase todo tempo tomado.

Só posso recomendar testar todos e chegar na sua conclusão de qual te ajuda melhor. Pessoas aleatórias na internet não poderão dizer o que é bom para você.

Acredito que outros aspectos não cabem aqui no SOpt.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu não quis dizer que esses softwares fariam toda a documentação pra mim. O que eles ajudam é no que você falou: o acabamento. Essa ajuda no acabamento faz toda a diferença na hora de se elaborar um manual, pois é nessa parte que as críticas mais acontecem e também onde mais demora para terminar. Se eu me expressei mal em relação a isso, me desculpe.

Comment: Não, não faz. O que faz a diferença é o que você colocar nele. Experimento ter um conteúdo ruim bem formatado e outro bom mal formato e veja qual ajuda mais. Esse acabamento ocupa um tempo mínimo, a ajuda é sempre bem-vinda mas não dá muito ganho perto do trabalho todo que é necessário.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar modelos do Editor de Textos para formatação do seu documento.

Se você dominar, você pode utilizar HTML com um Framework CSS e desenvolver um manual Web.

Você pode desenvolver um manual em Latex (também se interessar dominar). O acabamento é bom e é fácil de fazer depois que domina a linguagem.

Você pode criar video tutoriais no sistema.

Você pode utilizar um editor de apresentações com um modelo para deixar tudo padrão. Podendo até combinar com vídeos.

Você pode utilizar softwares de editoração como o Scribus para te ajudar no acabamento.